# Working outside the application context - Pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am new to python so please help me.

I am getting `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` when running pytest in environment.

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_route.py", line 2, in <module>
      from application import routes
      File "C:\Users\Propellente8\Documents\Valmee\Valmee_App\application\routes.py", line 111, in <module>
        @app.errorhandler(CustomException)
        File "C:\Users\Propellente8\Documents\Valmee\Valmee_App\senv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
        File "C:\Users\Propellente8\Documents\Valmee\Valmee_App\senv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
        return self.__local()
        File "C:\Users\Propellente8\Documents\Valmee\Valmee_App\senv\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
        raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
        RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

    This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the documentation for more information.
```

The Tree Structure of my app is as below:

```
    -App
      |-application
          |-__init__.py
          |-routes.py
      |-senv
      |-config.py
      |-test_route.py
      |-wsgi.py
```

In application/**init**.py, code is as below:

```
     from flask import Flask
     from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

     db = SQLAlchemy()

     def create_app():
"""Construct the core application."""
     app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

db.init_app(app)
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
with app.app_context():
    # Imports
    from . import routes

    return app
```

In application/routes.py, code is as below:

```
    from flask import request, jsonify
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from flask import current_app as app
    from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

    import psycopg2
    import pandas as pds
    import datetime as dt
    import json

    # Create an engine instance
    alchemyEngine   = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1/MyDb");

    # Connect to PostgreSQL server
    dbConnection    = alchemyEngine.connect();

    class CustomException(Exception):
status_code = 400

def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
    Exception.__init__(self)
    self.message = message
    if status_code is not None:
        self.status_code = status_code
    self.payload = payload

def to_dict(self):
    rv = dict(self.payload or ())
    rv['message'] = self.message
    return rv

    @app.errorhandler(CustomException)
     def handle_invalid_usage(error):
response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
response.status_code = error.status_code
return response

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
     def test():
        return "Hello"
    @app.route('/fail', methods=['GET'])
     def testFail():
      raise CustomException("raised exception")
```

In  config file,

```
    from os import environ
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    # app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1/Valmee_Analytics'
    class Config:

        # General Config
         SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
        FLASK_APP = environ.get('FLASK_APP')
        FLASK_ENV = environ.get('FLASK_ENV')

        # Database
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1/Valmee_Analytics'
```

In test_route.py file has below code:

```
    from application import create_app
    from application import routes

    def test_base_route():
        client = create_app.test_client()
        url = '/'

        response = client.get(url)
        assert response.get_data() == b'Hello, World!'
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

when I run pytest in the environment, I get the error. So please help with me fixing this.